# Changing passwords from existing database in laravel 4

Tags: php, passwords, laravel, laravel-4

I have an existing mysql database with a column of encrypted passwords using:

```
crypt($password, "ab");
```

I would like to change all those current passwords, so that Laravel 4 will recognize them and not fail authentication. How would I got about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new column, new_password for example, when users log in, then first check the passwords against the old encryption column, if it matches: hash the password with Laravel and  put them in the new_password column. After a while you can remove the old password column.